# Iterate over a tensor's rows and cols in Tensorflow

Tags: image, tensorflow, threshold, adaptive-threshold

A part of my project is to use a thresholding kernel on an image.
The thresholding kernel could look like this:

```
[50  100]
[150 200]
```

I would like to go over each group of 3x3 pixels (without overlap), and threshold them using my kernel.

For example, if I have this grayscale image:

```
[120 120 120 120]
[120 120 120 120]
[170 170 170 170]
[170 170 170 170]
```

Then after thresholding I should get this image:

```
[1 1 1 1]
[0 0 0 0]
[1 1 1 1]
[1 0 1 0]
```

I am using TensorFlow, and my network is needed with different shapes of batches.

The input is:

```
data['input_tensor'] = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None, None, 1], name='Input')
```

The thresholding kernel is of type: tf.Variable(), and size 5x5,
**AND ITS VALUES SHOULD BE LEARNED!**

I can't find a way to make it happen.
I tried iterating through the input batch, but its size is unknown (it is only known during a session).
I don't want to duplicate the thresholding kernel, because then the network will try to learn all of its values (and it's too much for now).

Is there a way to do it without loops?
If not, how could I do it with loops?

Thanks.